# How do I remove all characters after (and including) double underscores in a set of filenames in Windows?

Tags: r, windows, filenames

I have a set of filenames (ex. 12345__65432.vcf, 45678__87654.vcf) and am trying to find a code executable from an R script to be able to remove everything after (and including) the underscores in windows.
So far I have

```
WinCommand <- "ren *__?????.vcf *_.vcf"
shell(WinCommand, intern = TRUE)
```

This changes my filenames to "12345__.vcf and 45678__.vcf.

```
WinCommand <- "ren *__?????.vcf *.vcf"
shell(WinCommand, intern = TRUE)
```

Doesn't do anything

```
WinCommand <- "ren *.vcf ?????.vcf"
shell(WinCommand, intern = TRUE)
```

gives me the result  I want (12345.vcf and 45678.vcf), but I want this to work for filenames with possibly variable numbers of characters before the underscore. Please help!

Comment: How are the filenames accessed?  Do you build an array?  You'd probably want to use regular expressions to remove the characters you don't want and rename the filenames by looping through the array.

Comment: The command just changes the filenames directly within the specified folder without an array.